# Confusion related to the position of a string

Tags: c, c-strings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int f(char x[], char y[])
{
  int i, j, n = strlen(x) - strlen(y);
  while (n >= 0) {
    for (i = n, j = 0; y[j] != '\0' && x[i] == y[j]; ++i, ++j);
    if (j > 0 && y[j] == '\0')
      return n;
    n--;
  }

  return -1;
}

int main()
{
  f("knosos", "os");
}
```

Why does this return 4 instead of -1? Isn't `y[0]='\o'`?

Comment: `y[0]` is actually `'o'`

Comment: Maybe you can post an example input and expected output.

Comment: Well the example input is f("knosos", "os") and the output is 4 which is n's value, but I don't get how that for works..it's an exercise given by the teacher but the phrasing is messed up.

Comment: To understand 'how that works', the best way is to analyze what is the use of each term of the for-loop `for (i = n, j = 0; y[j] != '\0' && x[i] == y[j]; ++i, ++j);`. First tip `i = n` means that the function `f()` is a search_last substring.

Comment: I don't really see why the the test `j > 0` is necessary.

Comment: @FreekWiedijk, the if-condition `j > 0` is used to prevent searching an empty sub-string `y = ""`. In that case, `f()` returns `-1` (error) instead of `n`.

Answer (score 1):

This searches for the last occurrence of the string `y` in the string `x`.

In the `for` loop you compare at offset `n`, starting with the last position where comparison is meaningful. If you manage to get through the whole string `y` without failing the `x[i] == y[j]` test you found a match and return the offset `n`. If not, you decrease `n` and try again. Once `n` becomes less than zero that way, you have tried all positions for `y`, and give up by returning the offset `-1`.

So in your example the last occurrence of `"os"` in `"knosos"` is indeed at offset 4.

(Also there should be an `#include <string.h>` because you use `strlen`.)